# On the notion of primary representation of a natural number by a quadratic form

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms

This "discussion" has to do with some of the material we can find in pages 183-186 of the translation into English of the first part of E. Landau's *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie* (published by the Chelsea Publishing Co. in 1966).

1. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $F=\{a,b,c\}$, where $a>0$, be an integral binary quadratic form of discriminant $d>0$ such that $F(x,y)=k$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. We say that the previous representation of $k$ by $F$ is **primary** if

$$2ax+(b-\sqrt{d})y>0, \quad 1 \leq \frac{2ax+(b+\sqrt{d})y}{2ax+(b-\sqrt{d})y} <\varepsilon^{2}$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the fundamental solution of the equation $t^{2}-du^{2}=4$.

I believe that Landau defines a primary representation of a natural number $k$ by a form $F$ in this somewhat peculiar way because it will allow him to single out, for every $\ell$ such that

$$\ell^{2} \equiv d \pmod{4k}, \quad 0\leq \ell < 2k,$$

**exactly one** (*canonical*?) primary representation of $k$.

What can you tell me about this appreciation of mine? Is it dead wrong? How do you usually **motivate** this definition when you teach out of this famous book?

2. In pages 184-185, Landau proves the following:

Let us set

$$w= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
1 & \text{ if } d > \,\,\,\, 0 \\
2 & \text{ if } d < -4\\
4 & \text{ if } d=-4\\
6 & \text{ if } d=-3
\end{array}\right.$$

Then, for every $\ell$ such that

\begin{eqnarray}\ell^{2} \equiv d \pmod{4k},  \quad 0\leq \ell <2k,\end{eqnarray}

there are exactly $w$ proper primary representations of $k$ to which $\ell$ is associated (at this point of his exposition, Landau has already taught how to associate  to any proper representation of $k$ by a form a unique solution of $\ell^{2} \equiv d \pmod{4k}, 0\leq \ell <2k$, cf. Thm. 201 on page 180).

I consider that, for negative $d$'s, this assertion can be proved more succinctly as follows.

Let us fix and $\ell$ such that $\ell^{2} \equiv d \pmod{4k}, 0 \leq \ell < 2k$. Then, if $m:= \frac{\ell^{2}-d}{4k}$ and $G :=\{k,l,m\}$, it follows that $G \sim F_{i}$ for exactly one form $F_{i}$ in a complete set of representatives of the equivalence classes of primitive and positive-definite forms of discriminant $d$. Then, it is not difficult to convince oneself that there is a bijective correspondence between the proper primary (proper primary = proper, in the case of negative discriminants) representations of $k$ to which $\ell$ is associated and the matrices $g\in \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $gF_{i} = G$. Hence, since any such $g$ can be written in the form $g_{0}^{-1}A$ for a fixed $g_{0} \in \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $g_{0}G = F_{i}$ and any automorph $A$ of $F_{i}$, it does follow that the number of proper representations of $k$ to which $\ell$ is associated is equal to  the number of different automorphs of $F_{i}$ (which is exactly $w$).

I suppose that Landau's proof turns out to be a wee bit long-winded because he is trying to handle *simultaneously* the cases $d<0$ and $d>0$, right?

Please, let me thank you in advance for your attentive replies, comments, bibliographical suggestions, etc.

Comment: try it for Pell type equation, such as $x^2 - 19 y^2 = 85.$ Under the (oriented) automorphism group there are four orbits of solutions. A representative for each orbit can be picked by inequalities; it ought to be more clear, with $a=1, b=0, c = -19$ just what inequalities are meant.

Comment: 170^2 - 19 39^2 = 1

 u^2 - 19 v^2 = 85

Tue May 23 10:49:27 PDT 2017

u:  16  v:  3 ratio: 5.33333  SEED   KEEP +- 
u:  79  v:  18 ratio: 4.38889  SEED   KEEP +- 
u:  92  v:  21 ratio: 4.38095  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  79 ,  -18
u:  497  v:  114 ratio: 4.35965  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  16 ,  -3

Comment: @WillJagy: Would you be so kind as to elaborate a little?

Comment: I have some more errands to do, but I can get to this later. I do not know Landau's specific inequalities but I can likely work it out

Comment: what is $\varepsilon$ in terms of $(t,u)$ where you have $t^2 - d u^2 = 4 ?$ It appears $\varepsilon$ is a single real number.

Comment: $\varepsilon = \displaystyle \frac{t_{0}+u_{0}\sqrt{d}}{2}$ where $t_{0}, u_{0}$ is the smallest positive solution of $t^2-du^{2}=4$.

Comment: requested Landau book from library, might get it this week. If not, Tuesday, as Monday is a holiday here. It is not difficult to set up inequalities such that: every representation $ax^2 + bxy+ cy^2 = k$ can be acted on by the automorphism group ( an "equivalent" solution, in the same "orbit")  to produce a solution that satisfies the inequalities; next, no two solutions that satisfy the inequalities are "equivalent" under the group. After fiddling yesterday, I suspect Landau's way of doing this is different from mine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to take a more algebraic number theoretic approach to this question. The solutions to $x^2-dy^2=k$ are the integers of norm $k$ in the number field $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt(d)]$ if $d$ is a fundamental discriminant. Such integers are acted on by the unit group. To have a unique solution one must mod out by this action, but Landau singles out a unique representative instead. Those strange numbers $w$ are just the number of torsion units in various quadratic fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to leave a reply to this question of mine. In the case of negative discriminants, the $w$'s count the number of automorphs of any primitive form $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2}$ of disc. $d$; this number turns out to be exactly equal to the number of solutions of the equation $t^{2}−du^{2}=4$. Now, I have a question: in the beginning of your reply, did you mean to write "a more algebraic number theoretic"?

Answer (score 2):

I still need to go to the post office. However, yesterday I drew pictures of $x^2 - 19 y^2 = 85$ in Conway's topograph method. The three tree diagrams below give, together, four solutions to $x^2 - 19 y^2 = 85$ that are distinct modulo the action by the "automorph" 
$$  (x,y) \mapsto (170 x + 741y, 39 x + 170 y) $$ or its inverse
$$  (x,y) \mapsto (170 x - 741y, -39 x + 170 y) $$

My guess is that Landau's pair of inequalities pick out either the four solutions below (85 in pink, $x/y$ in green) or the first two along with negating either $x$ or $y.$

Back in a bit.

[image]
[image]
[image]